# jquery select box help needed

Tags: jquery, select

I have select box and option value has

United Kingdom
    United States

When i select "United Kingdom" as option i want two values "UK" as selected value and param value as 1

Any possiblity using jQuery?

Comment: I have to ask - what are you doing with the 'UK' & '1' values?
Are you using them on the client side or just posting them to the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the .data() function. First you have to set the data on your select options.

```
<option data-country="UK" data-value="1" selected="selected"></option>
```

Then you can get that data by doing the following:

```
$("option:selected").data("country");
$("option:selected").data("value");
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<select id="myid">
 <option value="0" class="US">United States</option>
 <option value="1" class="UK">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$('#myid').change(function (){
    var id   = $(this).val(); // 0 or 1
    var code = $(this).attr('class'); //UKorUS
    //do what u like with it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an 2D Array and keep both the required values and get both onchange event of dropdown